# I get "no match for 'operator=' when assigning value to a struct array iin C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, operator-keyword

I'm trying to read info from a file called AGENDA and place it in a struct type Persona*, which is shown after the code.

```
char arrk [120];
string dato;
arch_g.open("AGENDA.TDAT",ios::in);
//Persona* buffer;
do
{
    for (int k=0; k<tamano; k++)
    {
        arch_g.getline (arrk, 120, '\t');
        string dato (arrk);
        arreglo->nombre=dato;
        arreglo->apellido_p=dato;
        arreglo->apellido_m=dato;
        arreglo->dom.calle=dato;
        int dato1 = (int)arrk;
        arreglo->dom.numero=dato1;
        arreglo->dom.interior=dato;
        arreglo->dom.colonia=dato;
        arreglo->dom.ciudad =dato;
        arreglo->dom.estado=dato;
        dato1 = (int)arrk;
        arreglo->dom.codigo_postal=dato1;
        arreglo->tel.local=dato;
        arreglo->tel.clave_cd=dato;

        per[k] = arreglo;
    }

}
```

This is Persona

```
struct Persona

{
bool isInitialized;
std::string nombre;
std::string apellido_p;
std::string apellido_m;

Domicilio dom;
Telefono tel;

Persona() : isInitialized(false) {}

}
struct Domicilio
{
bool isInitialized;
std::string calle;
int numero;
std::string interior;
std::string colonia;
std::string ciudad;
std::string estado;
int codigo_postal;

Domicilio() : isInitialized(false) {}
};

struct Telefono
{
bool   isInitialized;
std::string    local;
std::string clave_cd;

Telefono() : isInitialized(false) {}
};
```

And the error I get is this:

error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Persona' and 'Persona*')|

The error is marked on the line ' per[k]=arreglo; '
This part refers to the Persona struct

note: candidate is:|
note: Persona& Persona::operator=(const Persona&)|
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Persona*' to 'const Persona&'|

Both per and arreglo are declared as global Persona*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `per` and `arreglo` are not defined. You should post a MCVE

Comment: @TheAspiringHacker Use `[mcve]` for a shorthand link for [mcve].

Comment: There ls a whole raft of magic codes like `mcve`: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer.  Take the value.  Or per whould have to be a Persona**

```
per[k] = *arreglo;
```

You may also need to implement the operator if the struct is non-trivial

```
Persona& operator=(const Persona& o) { ... }
```